# Issue while trying to browse localy stored HTML files on Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, browser, local

I am facing a problem.
Simply, I have a bunch of HTML-related files that I want to run locally on an Android device.
For example, I have an *index.html* file. It contains links to other HTML files, and when I try to click on those links to navigate to another HTML file, I get "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

An example of an anchor tag `<a href="add-component.html" >`

I am wondering if am I doing something wrong.
All the files are in the same directory, are spelled right, and have a valid .html extension. Every file is run separately.

I have tried using different web browsers.

Comment: You should have started to tell how you let Chrome display the index.html file to begin with. As now we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Also tell which url Chrome displays in its addressbar for index.html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html file and add-component.html file are in the same directory, you can use the following code for your anchor tag:

```
<a href="./add-component.html">
```

Comment: i have tried that

Answer (score 0):

For local files, you have got to use "file:///" at the start, like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:///add-component.html">
```